# how to return values to cshtml file using json in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my code.

I am getting an error:

> 'Json' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'variable'

```
//To view employee details with generic list       
public List<EmpModel> GetAllEmployees()
{           
     connection();
     con.Open();
     IList<EmpModel> EmpList = SqlMapper.Query<EmpModel>(con, "GetEmpUsingDapper1").ToList();
     con.Close();
     var data1 = EmpList.ToList();
     return Json (new { data = data1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: `public JsonResult GetAllEmployees()` (or `ActionResult`)

Comment: you should simply `return EmpList;`
also `var data1 = EmpList.ToList();` is redundant since you call `ToList` on a `List` which basically does nothing but eat cpu circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot convert type `JsonResult to List< T>` :

```
    public JsonResult GetAllEmployees()
    {
        connection();
        con.Open();
        IList<EmpModel> EmpList = SqlMapper.Query<RootObject>(con, "GetEmpUsingDapper1").ToList();
        //con.Close();
        var data1 = EmpList.ToList();
        return Json(new { data = data1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

or

```
    public List<EmpModel> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        connection();
        con.Open();
        IList<EmpModel> EmpList = SqlMapper.Query<EmpModel>(con, "GetEmpUsingDapper1").ToList();
        con.Close();
        //var data1 = EmpList.ToList();
        return EmpList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a JSON Result to a list. Follow the below code and it will work fine:

```
public JsonResult GetAllEmployees()
{           
    connection();
    con.Open();
    IList<EmpModel> EmpList = SqlMapper.Query<RootObject>(con, "GetEmpUsingDapper1").ToList();
    //con.Close();
    var data1 = EmpList.ToList();
    return Json(new { data = data1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```